# CustomPaint Over Camera Preview

Tags: camera, flutter, paint

I'm trying to use show a CustomPaint element over a camera preview in Flutter. Right now, the CustomPaint element is being shown under the camera preview. I'm using the [Flutter camera plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera) to show the camera preview. My code is below.

```
class _CameraPreviewState extends State<CameraPreview> {

  [...]

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

  return new YidKitTheme(
    new Center(
      child: _isReady
        ? new Container(
          height: height / 2,
          child: new CustomPaint(
            painter: new GuidelinePainter(),
            child: new AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: new CameraPreview(controller)
            ),
          )
        )
        : new CircularProgressIndicator()
      )
    );
  }
}

class GuidelinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = new Paint()
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    var path = new Path()..lineTo(50.0, 50.0);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
      child: new CustomPaint(
        painter: new GuidelinePainter(),
        child: new AspectRatio(
```

to

```
      child: new CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter: new GuidelinePainter(),
        child: new AspectRatio(
```

`painter` draws first (i.e. the background), then the `child` is drawn, then `foregroundPainter` draws last on top of the child